# Are US governments breaking the Leahy Law by supporting Israel?

Tags: united-states, israel, human-rights, palestine

As successive U.S. governments continue to provide various forms of support, including military weapons, despite the [human rights violations](https://www.ohchr.org/en/press-releases/2023/06/rights-civil-society-members-are-being-violated-all-entities-israel-and) committed by Israel against Palestinians over the past decades.

Are they breaking the [Leahy Law](https://www.state.gov/key-topics-bureau-of-democracy-human-rights-and-labor/human-rights/leahy-law-fact-sheet/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20Leahy%20law,of%20human%20rights%20(GVHR).)?

**EDIT**
From [Report on Human Rights Practices: Israel, West Bank and Gaza](https://www.state.gov/reports/2022-country-reports-on-human-rights-practices/israel-west-bank-and-gaza/)

> Significant human rights issues included credible reports of: unlawful
> or arbitrary killings; arbitrary or unjust detention, including of
> Palestinians in Israel and the occupied territories; restrictions on
> Palestinians residing in Jerusalem including arbitrary or unlawful
> interference with privacy, family, and home; substantial interference
> with the freedom of peaceful assembly and association; arbitrary or
> unlawful interference with privacy; punishment of family members for
> alleged offenses by a relative; restrictions on freedom of expression
> and media including censorship; harassment of nongovernmental
> organizations; violence against asylum seekers and migrants; violence
> or threats of violence against Palestinians and members of national,
> racial, or ethnic minority groups; and labor rights abuses against
> foreign workers and Palestinian workers.

Comment: What is the laehy law?

Comment: @Mocas Your assumption about "global consensus" is incorrect. This is a push question, voting to close.

Comment: Voting to reopen - This is a good question seeking clarification about a particular US policy and law, which can be factually answered. **It already has good answer that has been accepted**. (That some countries and organizations accuse Israel of human rights violation, while the US considers it as unverified or unfounded allegations is also a public fact).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

AFAICT, the Leahy law doesn't [ever] bar assistance to a country as a whole. It only bars assistance to specific *units* of the armed forces of a country that have committed GVHRs ("gross human rights violations"). And even in that case, the SecDef can "after consultation with the Secretary of State" decided that "The host government is taking all necessary corrective steps to bring to justice those responsible" and consequently resume US funding for that unit.

FWTW, according to one [brief](https://pomed.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/LeahyLaw_DutyToInform_FactSheet_web.pdf), the US has bilateral agreements with various countries to provide them  with a list of Leahy-barred units (by year of signing):

> 2021: ESTONIA, KOSOVO, MOROCCO, NORTH MACEDONIA, UKRAINE, **ISRAEL**
>
> 2022: GEORGIA, GREECE, JORDAN, LATVIA, MONTENEGRO, TUNISIA

However, the brief doesn't detail the exact units [if any] that may have [ever] been communicated to those countries.

Also

> the identity of prohibited units must generally be made publicly available. The Secretary of State, however, may exempt units from disclosure for national security reasons by providing a detailed justification for that determination to the House and Senate Appropriations Committees, House Foreign Affairs Committee, and Senate
> Foreign Relations Committee.

And [according](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leahy_Law) to Wikipedia the publication of such units was *always* waived, thus far:

> While the U.S. government does not publicly report on foreign armed forces units it has cut off from receiving assistance, press reports have indicated that security force and national defense force units in Australia, Bangladesh, Bolivia, Colombia, Guatemala, Mexico, Nigeria, Turkey, Indonesia, Lebanon, and Saint Lucia have been denied assistance due to the Leahy Law.

As you can see, Israel apparently never had any Leahy barred units, or if it did that didn't leak to the press.